# Explanation of two integral equations and implementation

Tags: integration

I have a problem with these two equations showing in the pictures.

Equation 1: 
[image: Equation 1]

Equation 2:
[image: Equation 1]

1.I have two vectors represented the C(m) and S(m) in the two equations. I am trying to implement these equations in Matlab. Instead of doing a continuous integral operation, I think I should do the summation. For example, the first equation

```
A1 = sqrt(sum(C.^2));
```

Am I right? Also, I am not sure how to implement equation two that contains a ||dM||. Please help.

2.What are the mathematical meaning of these two equations? I think the first one may related to the 'sum of squares', if C(m) is a vector then this equation will measure the total variance of the random variable in vector C or some kind of average of vector C? What about the second one?

Thanks very much for your help! A.